# Windows 7 blocks all dll's of my project when downloading project as a zip file from server

Tags: c#, windows-7, zip, wiki, blocking

Basically, I have release of my .net project in zip format, that I am putting on server for 
users to download.

When user downloads the project and extracts project.zip, then runs project.exe it gives the error of missing dll's.

The solution is to right click on Project.zip file and go to property and Unblock files. Then extract it again and then it works.

Website users downloading from is Wiki, I used to have old version of wiki and it worked properly, right now I switched to Wiki 2.0 and problem started to occur.

It seems like Windows 7 puts my Project.zip file in some kind of "unsafe" list. I am not sure what is the reason and if anyone already faced the same problem and know the solution please let me know.

Thanks

Comment: How about creating an installer that installs the dlls required by your application, for example, install .Net if the user does not have it?

Comment: Yeah, I know it might be a solution, but I can't do it due to stakeholders requirments